# Does $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}δ(x-y)\text{d}y = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$?

Tags: operator-theory, dirac-delta

Intuitively it seems that this should be the case but when attempting to apply this operator to a function $f$, we find

\begin{align*}
    \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} δ (y-x)\text{d} y\right)f(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(δ(y-x)f(x)\right)\text{d} y \\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(δ'(y-x)f(x)+δ (y-x)\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial y}\right) \text{d} y\\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(-δ(y-x)\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial y}+δ(y-x)\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial y}\right) \text{d} y\\
    &= 0 \neq \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}
\end{align*}

Comment: More helpful is $\int\partial_z[\delta(x-y)f(y,\,z)]dy=\partial_zf(x,\,z)$.

Comment: What is $\delta$?

Comment: $\delta$ is the dirac delta function $\int \delta(x-a)f(x)\text{d}x = f(a)$, $\delta'$ is the first derivative of the dirac delta which can be evaluated using integration by parts

Comment: What is the indefinite integral of s distribution?

Comment: I added integration bounds to clarify that I am not talking about indefinite integrals; the integral of operators $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} S_x\text{d}x$ should be defined to be the unique operator $T$ that has the property $Tf = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} S_x f\text{d}x $ for all $f$ in some function space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think even integration by parts interpretation works if you realize $\int \delta'(y-x) f(x) = \frac{\partial f(y)}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial y} = 0$. So now it works.

$$\int \delta'(y-x) f(x) = \int \lim_h \frac{(\delta(y+h-x)-\delta(y-x))}{h} f(x) $$ $$= \lim_h \frac{(\int\delta(y+h-x)f(x)-\int \delta(y-x)f(x))}{h}  = \lim_h \frac{(f(y+h)-f(y))}{h} =\frac{\partial f(y)}{\partial y}$$